# How do I add the Get-SBClientConfiguration command to PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure

I am using PowerShell ISE while working on Azure and ServiceBus
following tutorials about Azure.

A number of tutorials and walkthroughs use a command Get-SBClientConfiguration as well as other Service Bus related commands.

How do I add this command and the other Service Bus commands to PowerShell?